# Using a if/else statement in shell for netsat

Tags: shell, awk, netstat, ansible

My goal is to ensure that email connections are limited to outbound only

So I have two shell commands one is

```
netstat -an | grep ':25' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | wc -l
```

which prints out `1`

The command up above is finding all instances of port 25 besides localhost but does not exclude ipv6

The other command is

```
netstat -an | grep ':25' | grep -v '127.0.0.1\|::1' | wc -l
```

which prints out `0`

This command up above is finding all instances of port 25 and excluding localhost and ipv6

I need an if else that compares the two and says if it comes back 0 print out `compliant` else print out `non-compliant`

What is the best approach in doing that through either ansible or shell?

Comment: And what is the point of this? The connection is already established when you find out about the connection. The connection may be even already closed and the mail sent.

Comment: Its more for the person looking at and giving info about the connections.  So that the person can see that when it finds every instance of port 25 and excludes localhost and ipv6 its compliant and else its not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
netstat -an | grep ':25' | grep -v '127.0.0.1\|::1' | wc -l | awk '{if($0==0) print "compliant"; else print "non-compliant"}'
```

- will print `complaint` if output `$0` is 0
- else print `non-complaint`

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would handle it.

```
#!/bin/bash

if netstat -an | grep ':25' | grep -q -v '127.0.0.1\|::1'
then echo non-compliant
else echo compliant
fi
```

Bash if statements can handle return codes. If anything makes it through it will return a positive status and echo non-compliant, otherwise it's compliant

If that logic seems confusing you could also invert the status with a `!`

```
if ! netstat -an | grep ':25' | grep -q -v '127.0.0.1\|::1'
then echo compliant
else echo non-compliant
fi
```

Comment: @Kusalananda, nifty. Thanks for that one.